# IF in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm referencing a cell in google sheets using `=IF(SEARCH("United States",D14)>0,MID(D14,FIND(">",D14)+1,FIND("United States",D14)-FIND(">",D14)-3),MID(D14,FIND(">",D14)+1,FIND("Canada",D14)-FIND(">",D14)-3))`

D14 looks like this `Philadelphia, United States`

So my IF statement correctly returns Philadelphia. However, if I change it to a Canadian city, let's say `Toronto, Canada`, I receive this error: "In SEARCH evaluation, cannot find 'United States' within"

Am I using SEARCH incorrectly? Not sure

Comment: Can you create a test google sheet so I can understand better what you are asking? What is your goal with the formula?

Comment: Try finding the comma space which is the separator

Answer (score 0):

```
 =IF(SEARCH("United States",D14)>0,
 MID(D14,FIND(">",D14)+1,FIND("United States",D14)-FIND(">",D14)-3),
 MID(D14,FIND(">",D14)+1,FIND("Canada",D14)-FIND(">",D14)-3))
```

Not sure what you are trying to do, but when testing your formula on the given example, contrary to your claim it's not actually working.

In your `FIND`s you seem to be looking for `>` and not for comma which is your delimiter.  If you want to find whatever is after the comma, you can use a much simpler formula without any `IF`s

```
 =right(D14,len(D14)- find(", ",D14)-1)
```